# Why I'm unable to download a pdf file which is already present onto server?

Tags: php, file, pdf, download

Following is the code:

```
define(ADMIN_ROOT,'/var/www/abc/pqr/web/control/');
$filename = $test_data['test_name'];
$flname = ADMIN_ROOT.'modules/tests/test_pdfs/'.$filename;
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Accept-Ranges: none");      
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" .$flname. ".pdf\"");
```

The pdf file is already present over there at the directory

```
/var/www/abc/pqr/web/control/modules/tests/test_pdfs/
```

Also it has all the permissions assigned.But when I try to download a file, it's downloading some different file with same name but the file is not in a format which could be opened. In short the desired file is not getting downloaded. Can anyone please help me in correcting my issue?

Answer (score 3):

You must flush the file contents to the browser, headers won't do that. 
So: `readfile( $flname )` http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readfile.php

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php
$filename = $test_data['test_name'];
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/modules/tests/test_pdfs/" . $filename;

//$file = "/var/www/htdocs/audio/" . $filename;


                if (file_exists($file)) {
                        header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
                        header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . str_replace(" ", "_", basename($file)) . ";");
                        header ("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
                        readfile($file);
                        die();
                }
                else { 

                   //ERROR MESSAGE HERE..........
               }
 ?>
```

Please change this line

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
```

to

```
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also use the following code for download any type of file extensions:
<?php 
$filename = $test_data['test_name'];
$contenttype = "application/force-download";
header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\";");
readfile(ADMIN_ROOT.'modules/tests/test_pdfs/'.$filename);
exit();
?>
```